# SQL query - matching data between two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, ie;

In TableA there is around 10million rows,
In TableB there is around 500k rows

```
TableA (10million rows)
Url
-------------------------------------------
http://www.example.com/data/tuesday-morning
http://www.example.com/data/wednesday-evening



TableB (500k rows)
Keyword          Value
---------       ----------
Sunday              0
Monday              0
Tuesday             0
Wednesday           0
```

I want to search all keywords in `TableB` in `TableA`, and find the matches, which one matches to update their `Value` to `1`.

I use MERGE, but the problem is it takes at least 10 hours to make that search.

I will make that search everyday, because the KEYWORDs are updating daily in `TableB`

```
MERGE INTO TableB As TB 
USING (Select Url From TableA) As TA 
ON TA.Url LIKE 'http://www.example.com/data/'+TB.Keyword+'-%' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET TB.Value=1;
```

What will be the best SQL query to make the fastest lookup between these 2 tables?

Many Thanks

Comment: Get rid of `(Select Url From TableA) ` that for sure slows down your query, use just `TableA`

Comment: With this row amounts the only way - use full text indexes. That is - take approach proposed below by tinka (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39080778/2746150), but you have to replace `like '%'+t2.keyword+'%'` with language constructs specific to full-text indexes which are way faster.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your Q might be this solution will help you, you can apply some `WHERE` clause by ID or something so you can rectify whats going on with your record first apply with few data then you can apply with your all data.

```
 -- declare table1
 declare @table1 table
 (url varchar(max))

 insert into @table1
 values
 ('http://www.example.com/data/tuesday-morning'),
 ('http://www.example.com/data/tuesday-morning'),
 ('http://www.example.com/data/noday-morning')


 -- declare table2
 declare @table2 table
 (keyword varchar(33), val int)

 insert into @table2
 values
 ('monday',0),
 ('tuesday',0)

 -- select
 select * from 
 @table1 t1 join
 @table2 t2 on t1.url like '%'+t2.keyword+'%'

 -- update
 update
 @table2 
 set val =1 
 from 
 @table1 t1 join
 @table2 t2 on t1.url like '%'+t2.keyword+'%'

  -- select again
 select * from 
 @table1 t1 join
 @table2 t2 on t1.url like '%'+t2.keyword+'%'
```